# Django celery ImportError: no module named celery when using gunicorn bind?

Tags: python, django, command-line, celery, gunicorn

I have been searching everywhere for an answer to this. I am setting up a server for my Django website on Ubuntu 16.04 (digital ocean) and my Django site requires the use of celery for some periodic tasks.

It works in my development environment. And running `python manage.py celery beat` and `python manage.py celery worker` work just fine. It was all installed inside a virtualenv as well.

Here are my files:

`# __init__.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery_tasks import app as celery_app  # noqa
```

`# celery_tasks.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('myproject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

And this is the error that has been happening:

`# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`

```
File "/root/myproject/myproject/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .celery_tasks import app as celery_app  # noqa
File "/root/myproject/myproject/celery_tasks.py", line 4, in <module>
from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named celery
[2017-08-13 07:29:36 +0000] [5463] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5463)
[2017-08-13 07:29:36 +0000] [5458] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-08-13 07:29:36 +0000] [5458] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

There is also some more traceback which didn't seem as relevant.

Please, any help is MUCH appreciated. I think I'm missing something simple but I've been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Error says is not founding celery.
So put celery in your requirements.txt file, and when you deploy it installs Celery.
Or in your server do:

```
pip install celery
```

or insert celery in your requirements.txt and do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

../env_albo/bin/gunicorn albo.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
it worked)
need the path to gunicorn) which is in the virtual environment
The solution is deactivate venv
activate again...)

Comment: It looks like you are suggesting adding arguments to a command. Could you expand your answer to include the full command? Could you also clarify why adding these arguments solves the problem in the question?

Comment: Hi)
I just pointed out how I solved the problem - when I pointed the full path to gunicorn it worked properly...After that I reactivated the virtual environment and this error didn't occur anymore - gunicorn worked even without the full path (gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 albo.wsgi:application)...
My opinion-it has to do with the work of Pycharm